# create gradient color border shape in android

Tags: android, colors, shapes

in android, I want to define a `shape` file in `drawable` folder: `myShape.xml` such as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner"/>
    <stroke 
        android:width="5dp"
        android:color="@color/boder_endcall_color"/>
</shape>
```

And I want to create a gradient border in `<stroke />`, but actually I don't know how! So anyone can give a example of creating `shape` with `gradient` color in `stroke`?
Thanks!

**Edit:** I want `gradient` the color from `#F85C5C` (red) to `#F68282` (reddish).

Comment: How do you want the gradient in the border?

Comment: This question means, how to make gradient color in strokes.I tried it by <stroke 
        android:width="5dp"
        android:color="@drawable/strokes"/> And in strokes    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="@color/medium_gray_button"
        android:endColor="@color/light_gray_button"
        android:startColor="@color/dark_gray_button" />, so i got inflator exception

Comment: You can't use a gradient in the `stroke` tag. Anyway I don't know what you are trying to obtain, the two colors are almost similar and you're trying to setup the gradient between them on a `5dp` size which will make the gradient unnoticeable by the user on most devices.

Comment: @Luksprog If I can't use gradient in the `stroke`, so what should I do to make the color like gradient color?

Answer (score 1):

You best option is to use a nine-patch image which has the gradient already set to the desired colors(I don't see any easy way to do that gradient in a xml drawable).

For example, using your colors here is such a nine-patch(ignore my awful design skills):

[image: nine-patch image]

Of course, for best results, you should have different nine-patch images for different resolutions(ldpi, hdpi etc)

Comment: I think it is the good solution! However, I still wanna try another way!